# KeyError: 'data in one function but not in the others

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm trying to build a scraper for my smart mirror. I have built a python script to get weather, pollution level & news and something I don't get is why I am getting an error in this block of function when scraping the data instead of the other functions like the weather & pollution level. This is the code I am getting errors for:

```
def news(self):
        reddit1 = "https://www.reddit.com/r/LifeProTips/hot.json"
        reddit2 = "https://reddit.com/r/technology/hot.json"
        reddit3 = "https://reddit.com/r/Futurology/hot.json"
        reddit4 = "https://reddit.com/r/Showerthoughts/hot.json"
        lpt = requests.get(reddit1)
        tech = requests.get(reddit2)
        futu = requests.get(reddit3)
        show = requests.get(reddit4)
        lptd = json.loads(lpt.text)
        techd = json.loads(tech.text)
        futud = json.loads(futu.text)
        showd = json.loads(show.text)
        lpttitle = lptd['data']['children'][0]['data']['title']
        print(lpttitle)
        lptcontent = lptd['data']['children'][0]['data']['selftext']
        print(lptcontent)
        techttitle = techd['data']['children'][0]['data']['title']
        print(techtitle)
        techcontent = techd['data']['children'][0]['data']['selftext']
        print(techcontent)
        fututitle = futud['data']['children'][2]['data']['title']
        print(fututitle)
        futucontent = futud['data']['children'][0]['data']['selftext']
        print(futucontent)
        showtitle = showd['data']['children'][0]['data']['title']
        print(showdata)
        showcontent = showd['data']['children'][0]['data']['selftext']
        print(showcontent)
        lptdump = requests.put('firebaseurl',json={"Title": lpttitle, "Content": lptcontent})
        techdump = requests.put('firebaseurl',json={"Title": techtitle, "Content": techcontent})
        futudump = requests.put('firebaseurl',json={"Title": fututitle, "Content": futucontent})
        showdump = requests.put('firebaseurl',json={"Title": showtitle, "Content": showcontent})
```

but for a function like this:

```
def pollution(self):
    url = "api"
    url2 = "api"
    pm10 = requests.get(url)
    pm25 = requests.get(url2)
    pm10leveldata = json.loads(pm10.text)
    pm25leveldata = json.loads(pm25.text)
    pm10level = pm10leveldata[0]['data']
    pm25level = pm25leveldata[0]['data']
    print pm10level
    print pm25level
    # pm10 = round(pm10level)
    # pm25 = round(pm25level)
    pdump = requests.put('firebaseurl',json={"Pm10": pm10level, "Pm25": pm25level})
```

No errors. Why am I getting a key error at that one but not in a function like this

Comment: On what line is the error occurring?

Comment: @ColinBasnett it occurs on the line:  `lpttitle = lptd['data']['children'][0]['data']['title']` if i uncomment it goes to the others

Comment: Print out `lptd` before that line executes and see if the key actually does exist. Chances are you're making an assumption about the format of the data that isn't true.

Comment: it prints out the json + it doesn't crash anymore but it crashes on the other objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Print out `lptd` before you try to use it:

```
{'error': 429, 'message': 'Too Many Requests'}
```

You have angered reddit. This could happen on any request, so it could appear as though the error is jumping around.

As an aside, you can get the json from requests directly:

```
lptd = requests.get(reddit1).json()
```

Comment: Thanks mate. That's one of the problem and put a time.sleep around it to don't piss it off. Plus idk how but when printing lptd and the rest the others don't crash

Comment: I don't know either... The first couple of times I ran your script it worked for me, then started failing. Maybe its tracked for a significant amount of time and its the delay between your test runs that make a difference.